# Adaptive columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, responsive

Please help me
I have a list of names in alphabetical order (number of names unknown).
I need to make a responsive layout, on the mobile version 1 column, on the desktop version 2-3 columns.

I know how to do this
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9vwP.png)

A B C

D E F

G H I

but I need to do like this
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCasg.png)

A D G

B E H

C F I

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Hi Serhii, you need to add your code so others can help you.  See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For guidance on what to submit please read [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for anyone to help you in any meaningful way.

Comment: However... to get columns like you want you can use the [columns property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.php) and use a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php) to set a break point at small screen sizes, like mobile.

Comment: If you want to use [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) then look up `grid-auto-flow: column`.

Comment: I've dropped you an example [here](https://codepen.io/adamuk73/pen/dyqmbpo). Can you use the guidelines on your next question. If you do then in future, other users can use your question to solve their problems too and you'll get a proper answer .

Comment: @Adam Thanks a lot, I used the columns property, this is what I needed!

Comment: You're very welcome Serhii. Don't forget to post your code next time you ask a question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.